# Invalid JSON object error: NewtonSoft Json

Tags: json, json.net

I am getting execption while parsing the below JSON using JSONConvert

```
{'d':{
  'results': [
    {
      '__metadata': {
        'id': 'a4ddaefa-8014-450e-84ff-dada399707',
        'uri': 'https://some.server.com/_api/Web/Lists(**GUID**'aaaa-bbbb-cccc-b7b0-eeeee')/Items(1)',
        'etag': '\'1\'',
        'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem'
      },
      'Title': 'sadfsdf'
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Its throwing error for character after GUID.

Appreciate any help or pointers

Comment: Check syntax errors with JSONLint (http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thanks Binkan. But this JSON I am getting dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                     "id": "a4ddaefa-8014-450e-84ff-dada399707",
                    "uri": "https: //some.server.com/_api/Web/Lists(**GUID**'aaaa-bbbb-cccc-b7b0-eeeee')/Items(1)",
                    "etag": "'1'",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem"
                },
                "Title": "sadfsdf"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

or formatted compact:

```
{\"d\":{\"results\":[{\"__metadata\":{\"id\":\"a4ddaefa-8014-450e-84ff-dada399707\",\"uri\":\"https: \/\/some.server.com\/_api\/Web\/Lists(**GUID**\'aaaa-bbbb-cccc-b7b0-eeeee\')\/Items(1)\",\"etag\":\"\'1\'\",\"type\":\"SP.Data.TestListItem\"},\"Title\":\"sadfsdf\"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid in jsonlint.com.  Change single quotes to double except for the uri.

```
{
"d": {
    "results": [
            {
            "__metadata": {
                    "id": "a4ddaefa-8014-450e-84ff-dada399707",
                    "uri": "https: //some.server.com/_api/Web/Lists(**GUID**'aaaa-bbbb-cccc-b7b0-eeeee')/Items(1)",
                    "etag": "\"1\"",
                    "type": "SP.Data.TestListItem"
                },
                "Title": "sadfsdf"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```